# many things in one query. is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have three tables

### menus

```
+--id---ident---+
|--1----menu_1--|
```

### menus_data

```
+--id---id_parent---name---------id_lang--+
|--1----1-----------menu_eng------1-------|
|--2----1-----------menu_rus------2-------|
+--3----1-----------menu_arm------3-------+
```

### languages

```
+--id---name--------+
|--1----english-----|
|--2----russian-----|
|--3----armenian----|
```

second table store the data about menus (names in all languages), ie. id_parent of second table is id of first.

let's asume i add a new language, with id=4. now i need to give the default values( which must br equal to `id_lang` = 1 value) to all menus, so i need to add row in `menus_data` table

`|--4----1-----------menu_eng------4-------|`

and i must do it with all menus from `menus` table.

I can do it with tree queries -

1. find the list of all menus from `menus` table
2. find the default value ov each element
3. add row in `menus_content` table with that values

but maybe it is possible to do in one query?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need id and id_lang? Are they always going to be the same value?

Comment: And where is the Menus_Content table?

Comment: `id_lang` is id from another `languages` table, where i store list of all languages.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish? There might be a better approach overall for your needs. Too, languages is where you store the languages, but why is there 'menu_eng' or 'menu_rus' in the `menus_data` table?

Comment: @Syom: Is there any possibility that you are `menus` records that do **not** have supporting records in the `menus_data` table?  If the answer is "no", there's no reason to perform what you listed as step 1...

Comment: it is the names of menu in other languages. menu_eng is name in english, menu_rus, in Russian, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible. It would be something like this:

```
insert into `menus_data` select null, `id_parent`, `name`, 4 from `menus_data` where `id_lang` = 1;
```

I haven't checked that, so the syntax may be a little off. The query also assumes that there is a record for id_lang=1 in menus_data for every menu.

More info on this type of query here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: i like this new type of queries( new, for me;)

**Thanks**